# How to animate stroke in svg image on hover

Tags: javascript, css, svg

I'm trying to make a single stroke in my svg drawing to be highlighted on hover.
Is it possible to be done with css or do I need to use javascript?

Here's my html:

```
    <svg version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px" width="1024px"
   height="768px" viewBox="0 0 1024 768" enable-background="new 0 0 1024 768" xml:space="preserve">
<g id="Warstwa_1">
  <g>
    <path fill="none" stroke="#00755F" stroke-miterlimit="10" d="M825.61,601.428c0-55.844-117.614,25.921-257.144,29.87
      c-137.662,3.896-176.422-82.646-210.389-81.817c-53.246,1.299,6.986,64.935,6.986,64.935">  <animate dur="0.1s" to="#000000" from="#00755F" attributeName="stroke" begin="mouseover"/>
    <animate  dur="0.1s" to="#4e86b1" from="#00755F" attributeName="stroke" begin="mouseout"/></path>
    <path fill="none" stroke="#00755F" stroke-miterlimit="10" d="M826.179,592.094c0-55.844-121.106,41.499-260.634,44.886
      c-135.795,3.409-172.364-99.479-208.035-95.535c-50.922,5.629,9.69,69.933,9.69,69.933">  <animate  dur="0.1s" to="#000000" from="#00755F" attributeName="stroke" begin="mouseover"/>
    <animate  dur="0.1s" to="#4e86b1" from="#000000" attributeName="stroke" begin="mouseout"/></path>
    <path fill="none" stroke="#00755F" stroke-miterlimit="10" d="M826.747,582.759c0-55.844-124.6,57.077-264.124,59.902
      c-133.929,2.922-167.956-116.474-205.682-109.252c-48.385,9.262,12.395,74.93,12.395,74.93"/>
    <path fill="none" stroke="#00755F" stroke-miterlimit="10" d="M827.314,573.425c0-55.844-128.091,72.655-267.613,74.919
      c-132.062,2.434-163.305-133.679-203.328-122.971c-45.755,12.242,15.098,79.928,15.098,79.928"/>
    <path fill="none" stroke="#00755F" stroke-miterlimit="10" d="M827.883,564.09c0-55.844-131.584,88.234-271.104,89.936
      c-130.195,1.947-158.511-151.123-200.974-136.688c-43.118,14.657,17.802,84.925,17.802,84.925"/>
    <path fill="none" stroke="#00755F" stroke-miterlimit="10" d="M828.451,554.756c0-55.844-135.076,103.812-274.595,104.951
      c-128.328,1.461-153.666-168.831-198.62-150.405c-40.533,16.613,20.506,89.923,20.506,89.923"/>
    <path fill="none" stroke="#00755F" stroke-miterlimit="10" d="M829.02,545.422c0-55.844-138.568,119.39-278.085,119.967
      c-126.461,0.974-153.608-194.835-196.266-164.123c-40.653,11.203,23.209,94.921,23.209,94.921"/>
    <path fill="none" stroke="#00755F" stroke-miterlimit="10" d="M829.588,536.087c0-55.844-142.062,134.968-281.575,134.983
      c-124.594,0.486-149.806-213.533-193.912-177.84c-38.554,12.853,25.913,99.918,25.913,99.918"/>
    <path fill="none" stroke="#00755F" stroke-miterlimit="10" d="M830.156,526.753c0-55.844-145.554,150.546-285.065,149.999
      c-122.728,0-146.004-232.231-191.559-191.558c-36.455,14.504,28.617,104.915,28.617,104.915"/>
    <path fill="none" stroke="#00755F" stroke-miterlimit="10" d="M830.724,517.419c0-55.844-149.045,166.124-288.555,165.016
      c-120.861-0.487-135.317-242.556-189.205-205.276c-31.222,21.599,31.321,109.913,31.321,109.913"/>
    <path fill="none" stroke="#00755F" stroke-miterlimit="10" d="M831.292,508.084c0-55.844-152.538,181.702-292.045,180.032
      c-118.994-0.975-131.311-261.733-186.852-218.993c-29.2,22.47,34.025,114.91,34.025,114.91"/>
    <path fill="none" stroke="#00755F" stroke-miterlimit="10" d="M831.86,498.75c0-55.844-156.03,197.28-295.535,195.048
      c-117.127-1.462-127.649-281.201-184.498-232.711c-27.306,23.291,36.729,119.908,36.729,119.908"/>
    <path fill="none" stroke="#00755F" stroke-miterlimit="10" d="M832.429,489.416c0-55.844-159.522,212.857-299.026,210.063
      c-115.26-1.948-124.374-300.938-182.143-246.429c-25.538,24.097,39.433,124.906,39.433,124.906"/>
    <path fill="none" stroke="#00755F" stroke-miterlimit="10" d="M832.997,480.081c0-55.844-163.016,228.437-302.517,225.08
      c-113.393-2.435-121.518-320.91-179.79-260.146c-23.895,24.917,42.137,129.903,42.137,129.903"/>
    <path fill="none" stroke="#00755F" stroke-miterlimit="10" d="M833.564,470.747c0-55.844-166.507,244.015-306.006,240.097
      c-111.526-2.923-119.102-341.081-177.436-273.864c-22.373,25.78,44.84,134.901,44.84,134.901"/>
    <path fill="none" stroke="#00755F" stroke-miterlimit="10" d="M834.133,461.412c0-55.844-170,259.593-309.496,255.113
      c-109.66-3.41-117.128-361.4-175.082-287.581c-20.965,26.704,47.544,139.898,47.544,139.898"/>
    <path fill="none" stroke="#00755F" stroke-miterlimit="10" d="M834.701,452.078c0-55.844-173.492,275.171-312.986,270.129
      c-107.793-3.896-115.586-381.818-172.729-301.299c-19.664,27.709,50.248,144.896,50.248,144.896"/>
  </g>/g></svg>
```

As you can see I tried 'animate' but it doesn't work.
I also tried css like here:

```
g#Warstwa_1 path
{ stroke: red; }
g#Warstwa_1:hover path { stroke: blue; }
```

This makes the whole image to change color instead of a single line.

Here's live example:
http://www.ewelinawoloszyn.com/index11.html

Any suggestions are more than welcome. Many thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: Paulie I've changed CSS but it only image red. Hover doesn't seem to work.

Comment: Is it possible to add class to each path?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to add closing tag for .hi class and added

```
g#Warstwa_1_kopia {
 display:block; 
}
```

Then Paulie_D CSS worked.

Answer (score 1):

You need to set the `:hover` state on the actual `path` element.

Also note that your SVG has a malformed closing `<g>` at the end.

```css
svg {
  margin-top: -200px;
  /* demo positioning */
}

#Warstwa_1 path {
  stroke-width: 2px;
  /* for demo pusposes only */
  transition: stroke .4s;
}

#Warstwa_1 path:hover {
  stroke: red;

}
```

```html
<svg version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px" viewBox="0 0 1024 768" enable-background="new 0 0 1024 768" xml:space="preserve">
<g id="Warstwa_1">
  <g>
    <path fill="none" stroke="#00755F" stroke-miterlimit="10" d="M825.61,601.428c0-55.844-117.614,25.921-257.144,29.87
      c-137.662,3.896-176.422-82.646-210.389-81.817c-53.246,1.299,6.986,64.935,6.986,64.935">  <animate dur="0.1s" to="#000000" from="#00755F" attributeName="stroke" begin="mouseover"/>
    <animate  dur="0.1s" to="#4e86b1" from="#00755F" attributeName="stroke" begin="mouseout"/></path>
    <path fill="none" stroke="#00755F" stroke-miterlimit="10" d="M826.179,592.094c0-55.844-121.106,41.499-260.634,44.886
      c-135.795,3.409-172.364-99.479-208.035-95.535c-50.922,5.629,9.69,69.933,9.69,69.933">  <animate  dur="0.1s" to="#000000" from="#00755F" attributeName="stroke" begin="mouseover"/>
    <animate  dur="0.1s" to="#4e86b1" from="#000000" attributeName="stroke" begin="mouseout"/></path>
    <path fill="none" stroke="#00755F" stroke-miterlimit="10" d="M826.747,582.759c0-55.844-124.6,57.077-264.124,59.902
      c-133.929,2.922-167.956-116.474-205.682-109.252c-48.385,9.262,12.395,74.93,12.395,74.93"/>
    <path fill="none" stroke="#00755F" stroke-miterlimit="10" d="M827.314,573.425c0-55.844-128.091,72.655-267.613,74.919
      c-132.062,2.434-163.305-133.679-203.328-122.971c-45.755,12.242,15.098,79.928,15.098,79.928"/>
    <path fill="none" stroke="#00755F" stroke-miterlimit="10" d="M827.883,564.09c0-55.844-131.584,88.234-271.104,89.936
      c-130.195,1.947-158.511-151.123-200.974-136.688c-43.118,14.657,17.802,84.925,17.802,84.925"/>
    <path fill="none" stroke="#00755F" stroke-miterlimit="10" d="M828.451,554.756c0-55.844-135.076,103.812-274.595,104.951
      c-128.328,1.461-153.666-168.831-198.62-150.405c-40.533,16.613,20.506,89.923,20.506,89.923"/>
    <path fill="none" stroke="#00755F" stroke-miterlimit="10" d="M829.02,545.422c0-55.844-138.568,119.39-278.085,119.967
      c-126.461,0.974-153.608-194.835-196.266-164.123c-40.653,11.203,23.209,94.921,23.209,94.921"/>
    <path fill="none" stroke="#00755F" stroke-miterlimit="10" d="M829.588,536.087c0-55.844-142.062,134.968-281.575,134.983
      c-124.594,0.486-149.806-213.533-193.912-177.84c-38.554,12.853,25.913,99.918,25.913,99.918"/>
    <path fill="none" stroke="#00755F" stroke-miterlimit="10" d="M830.156,526.753c0-55.844-145.554,150.546-285.065,149.999
      c-122.728,0-146.004-232.231-191.559-191.558c-36.455,14.504,28.617,104.915,28.617,104.915"/>
    <path fill="none" stroke="#00755F" stroke-miterlimit="10" d="M830.724,517.419c0-55.844-149.045,166.124-288.555,165.016
      c-120.861-0.487-135.317-242.556-189.205-205.276c-31.222,21.599,31.321,109.913,31.321,109.913"/>
    <path fill="none" stroke="#00755F" stroke-miterlimit="10" d="M831.292,508.084c0-55.844-152.538,181.702-292.045,180.032
      c-118.994-0.975-131.311-261.733-186.852-218.993c-29.2,22.47,34.025,114.91,34.025,114.91"/>
    <path fill="none" stroke="#00755F" stroke-miterlimit="10" d="M831.86,498.75c0-55.844-156.03,197.28-295.535,195.048
      c-117.127-1.462-127.649-281.201-184.498-232.711c-27.306,23.291,36.729,119.908,36.729,119.908"/>
    <path fill="none" stroke="#00755F" stroke-miterlimit="10" d="M832.429,489.416c0-55.844-159.522,212.857-299.026,210.063
      c-115.26-1.948-124.374-300.938-182.143-246.429c-25.538,24.097,39.433,124.906,39.433,124.906"/>
    <path fill="none" stroke="#00755F" stroke-miterlimit="10" d="M832.997,480.081c0-55.844-163.016,228.437-302.517,225.08
      c-113.393-2.435-121.518-320.91-179.79-260.146c-23.895,24.917,42.137,129.903,42.137,129.903"/>
    <path fill="none" stroke="#00755F" stroke-miterlimit="10" d="M833.564,470.747c0-55.844-166.507,244.015-306.006,240.097
      c-111.526-2.923-119.102-341.081-177.436-273.864c-22.373,25.78,44.84,134.901,44.84,134.901"/>
    <path fill="none" stroke="#00755F" stroke-miterlimit="10" d="M834.133,461.412c0-55.844-170,259.593-309.496,255.113
      c-109.66-3.41-117.128-361.4-175.082-287.581c-20.965,26.704,47.544,139.898,47.544,139.898"/>
    <path fill="none" stroke="#00755F" stroke-miterlimit="10" d="M834.701,452.078c0-55.844-173.492,275.171-312.986,270.129
      c-107.793-3.896-115.586-381.818-172.729-301.299c-19.664,27.709,50.248,144.896,50.248,144.896"/>
  </g></g></svg>
```

Comment: This is what I wanted.Thank you! It looks beautiful :)

Comment: Paulie_D I've tried your code on live example and it doesn't seem to work. Could you take a look? http://www.ewelinawoloszyn.com/index11.html

Comment: You haven't removed your original attempt `g#Warstwa_1:hover path { stroke: blue; }` Remove that and it should work.

Comment: Paulie_D strange I've double checked the code it should work but it doesn't even if I force hover state in google inspect preview.

Comment: I had a script running  and after removing it animate seem to work but duration option makes interaction too short. Is it possible to make it similar to responsiveness in the snippet? Maybe there is duration:auto option?

Comment: Just use a `transition` - I added one to the snippet.

Comment: Thanks Paulie_D. I'm still wrecking my brain why your CSS solution doesnt work on live example and animate does. It's much more labor intensive to do it with animate as the whole svg is much bigger.

Answer (score -1):

for animation, you can use this code(CSS-animation) and modify according to your requirement

```
svg:hover path {
 stroke-dasharray: 1000;
  stroke-dashoffset: 1000;
  animation: dash 5s linear forwards;
}

@keyframes dash {
  to {
    stroke-dashoffset: 0;
    stroke: blue;
  }
}
```

here I apply hover effect on svg(tag).

and for more details about [CSS-animation](https://css-tricks.com/svg-line-animation-works/) check the link.